# Populate UIView with UIVIewController in a Navigation Based App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, setter

I'm making a test application for listing movies in a Navigation Based Application using data from a plist file that I read in my appDelegate in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. When I try to go to the second detailViewController I get the title partially changed (I get the title of the movie but instead of the year in the `UIView.title` I get something like "78898320" & empty UIImageView & UILabels. What am I missing?

[image: Populated from my app rootViewController]

[image: Populated from my app detailViewController]

Here is my method in the rootViewController:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
NSLog(@"YOU SELECTED: %d",indexPath.row);

detailViewController *detailView = [[detailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"detailViewController" bundle:nil];

NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:
                      [movies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

[detailView fill:dict];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
[detailView release];

}
```

Here is my method for filling the UIView in the detailViewController:

```
-(void)fill: (NSDictionary*) fillData
{
//movie = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:fillData];
NSLog(@"DETAILS: %@",[fillData objectForKey:@"description"]);

self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%d)",
              [fillData objectForKey:@"title"],
              [fillData objectForKey:@"year"]];
//[movie objectForKey:@"title"];
self.img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
            [UIImage imageNamed:[fillData objectForKey:@"image"]]];
self.description = [fillData objectForKey:@"description"];
self.cast = [fillData objectForKey:@"cast"];
}
```

When I try to print the description from the dictionary using NSLog it prints out fine.

Comment: how are `self.title`, `self.img`, ... declared in `detailViewController` ?

Comment: nothing jumps out at me, you should set a breakpoint and step through it.

Comment: Just set detailView.title = @"Transformers". you will not get those numbers.

Comment: @Vince self.title is the title of the View, while img, description & cast are UIImageView & 2 UILabels defined in the viewController's interface.
@Legolas, I don't have anymore problems with the title, only the UIImageView & UILabels are bothering me now.

Comment: As you can see in you're answer below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to change some things to do it working. I guess all your labels and image views are actually in a NIB file.

By doing :

```
self.img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
            [UIImage imageNamed:[fillData objectForKey:@"image"]]];
```

you are actually breaking the connection between the property and the object in the NIB file, by replacing it with a fresh new instance. Unless you add manually the new one to the view, nothing can appear.

Try using :

```
[self.img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[fillData objectForKey:@"image"]]];
```

The same applies to :

```
self.description = [fillData objectForKey:@"description"];
self.cast = [fillData objectForKey:@"cast"];
```

Try instead :

```
[self.description setText:[fillData objectForKey:@"description"]];
[self.cast setText:[fillData objectForKey:@"cast"]];
```

Comment: Yes indeed.. when I pass the data through an NSDictionary in my `fillData:` method & I use the data in `ViewWillAppear:` method to populate my properties.. It actually works.. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

You are using `%d` for the object that you get using

```
[fillData objectForKey:@"year"]
```

You should use `%@` instead as it is most likely an `NSNumber` object.

Comment: You're right. I should use `%@` as I used in my NSLog..
Now that part work fine, but why my UIImageView & UILabels aren't populated?

Comment: Where are you populating them? The correct point would be `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear:` as the outlet connections aren't made prior to it. If you are doing that already then check your outlet connections.

Comment: My IBOutlet connections are fine.. Also now I tried to initialize a NSDictionary inside FillData method & use it later to populate the UIImageView & UILabels inside ViewWillAppear.. When it reached there the NSDictionary was containing the data but it didn't populated them.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)fill: (NSDictionary*) fillData
{
    //movie = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:fillData];
    NSLog(@"DETAILS: %@",[fillData objectForKey:@"description"]);

    self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%d)",
          [fillData objectForKey:@"title"],
          [[fillData objectForKey:@"year"] intValue]];
    //[movie objectForKey:@"title"];
    self.img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
          [UIImage imageNamed:[fillData objectForKey:@"image"]]];
    self.description = [fillData objectForKey:@"description"];
    self.cast = [fillData objectForKey:@"cast"];
}
```

If you are not getting Image in image view because ur not setting its frame and you are not adding it to view (atleast here)....